# call a function return from another function

Tags: matlab

I've function1 that returns a value which is editText.
from another function2, I would like to get the function1 to after type a text
I tried

```
function function2(arg)
editTextarea = @()function2(arg)
editTextarea....
```

is this correct ?

Answer (score 0):

I am confused by your question?  Are you saying that you have a main function `function1` that contains a sub-function `function2` and that you would like to be able to call the sub-function directly?

If so then refer to this [Mathworks support article](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-19LN6/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-19LN6)

> The first method to call a subfunction from outside a main function is
>   to create a function handle to the subfunction inside the main
>   function (where the subfunction is in scope) and return it as an extra
>   output argument. You can then use FEVAL to evaluate the function
>   handle, passing it any arguments the subfunction accepts. The reason
>   this works is that a function handle records the scope of the function
>   or subfunction in which it was created. A simple example of how to do
>   this is:

```
function y=myfun(varargin)

if nargin==0 % There are no input arguments, I assume you are asking for the function handle  
y=@mysubfun; % This only works in MATLAB 6.0 (R12) and above else % There is an input argument, I assume you want to evaluate the main function  
y=2*varargin{1}
end

function t=mysubfun(z)
t=3*z;
```

> Now, if you type:

```
H=myfun;  
y1=myfun(1); 
y2=feval(H,1); 
[y1 y2]
```

> You receive the result:
>
> ans =
>        2     3